# phlist1; guide to UNIX using Linux chapter 6 project 19

Tags: shell, awk, scripting, command, project

i can't seem to run my script. Here is the code:

```
clear
tput cup 2 20; echo "Corporate Phone List"
tput cup 3 20; echo "===================="
tput cup 5 0;
awk -F: '{printf "%-12s %-12s %s\t%s %s %10.10s %s\n". $2, $3 ,$3, $1, $5, $6, $7}' corp_phones
```

Comment: What happens? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: Should the `.` be a `,` in this bit?  `%s\n". $2,`